# Tips on ensuring your website will look proper on a mobile browser?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have made a few websites in my day, but ever since the mobile browser i've been having problems getting my websites to look properly in browsers like mobile safari, I have not changed my programming habits to accomodate, and I am not sure exactly what to change to fix the errors I am getting. For example:

http://generationsbeyond.com/immersa/

It's a gorgeous microsite when viewed in a desktop browser, but when viewed in a mobile browser some elements, specifically ones that are 100% width, get skewed.

Examples of that:

http://imgur.com/WsrhM,1e1tH#0

It seems everything is just wrong, I know there could be something with my css habits that may possibly prevent this in the future.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, use two stylesheets. When linking to them in your HTML use media="..." attribute in the link tag to specify what device each one is for. So one would have media="handheld" and the other would have media="screen". Adjust the CSS file for handheld until it looks good.

So when a PC user goes to your website the CSS file related to media="screen" will be loaded, but if a handheld user enters, the other will be used. Do note that the safari browser on certain handhelds will identify itself as a regular browser and not a handheld. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using some css sheets with grid systems could be helpfull.
Sadly, I don't think you can make your sites more 'device friendly' without rewriting almost entirely your app :/.

Anyway, some recomendations:
 - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ Responsive css can be just what you need
 - http://cssgrid.net/ Perhaps implementing this will be less radical